# How to toggle Add Mesh perspective

Tags: interface, customization

this is really dumb but theres something in the preferences of Blender 2.92 that you can change the orientation of an object/mesh when added to follow either the world or your viewpoint position. I changed it to viewpoint position as part of a tutorial and cannot remember how to change it back and I HATE IT.
Please can someone tell me how to change it back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences > Editing > Align to World.

[image]